# Unix - Convert GMT time field to PST time

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Sorry if this has been asked before.

I have a text file that contain a field with GMT time on Unix. I want to convert that field to the PST time zone in the same format.

source file test.txt

```
20200804T221806.214 GMT,2003060015,2003060018
20200804T232027.571 GMT,2005260045,2005260095
20200804T232027.572 GMT,2005260045,2005260095
20200805T000119.715 GMT,2005290022C,2005290042D
20200805T000119.715 GMT,2005290022C,2005290042D
20200801T000326.111 GMT,2005290028C,2005290050D
20200101T000326.111 GMT,2005290028C,2005290050D
20000101T000326.111 GMT,2005290028C,2005290050D
```

Desired result

```
20200804T151806.214 PST,2003060015,2003060018
20200804T162027.571 PST,2005260045,2005260095
20200804T162027.572 PST,2005260045,2005260095
20200804T000119.715 PST,2005290022C,2005290042D
20200804T000119.715 PST,2005290022C,2005290042D
20200731T000326.111 PST,2005290028C,2005290050D
20191231T000326.111 PST,2005290028C,2005290050D
19991231T000326.111 PST,2005290028C,2005290050D
```

This is my current awk code and got the result. However, this solution only works if all months have the same 31 days. I feel like there should be a much simpler solution for this and not necessary to use awk.

```
awk -F ',' '{ sCCYY = substr($1,1,4); sMM = substr($1,5,2); sDD = substr($1,7,2); stime = substr($1,10,6) - 70000; if (stime < 0) { sDD = sDD - 1; stime = substr($1,10,6); if (sDD <= 0) { sMM = sMM - 1; sDD = 31; if (sMM <= 0) { sCCYY = sCCYY - 1; sMM = 12; } } } printf"%04s%02s%02s%06s%s%s%s\n",sCCYY,sMM,sDD,"T" stime,substr($1,16,4) " PST,",$2 ",",$3; }' test.txt
```

result:

```
20200804T151806.214 PST,2003060015,2003060018
20200804T162027.571 PST,2005260045,2005260095
20200804T162027.572 PST,2005260045,2005260095
20200804T000119.715 PST,2005290022C,2005290042D
20200804T000119.715 PST,2005290022C,2005290042D
20200731T000326.111 PST,2005290028C,2005290050D
20191231T000326.111 PST,2005290028C,2005290050D
19991231T000326.111 PST,2005290028C,2005290050D
```

Please share if you know a better way to convert it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have (or can you install) GNU awk for time functions?

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton, I am not sure if we can install GNU on our system. We have to check with our system admin. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU awk for time functions then:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    match($1,/(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})T(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})\.(.{3})/,a)
    secs = mktime(a[1]" "a[2]" "a[3]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6], 1)
    $1 = strftime("%FT%T."a[7]" %Z", secs)
    print
}
```

.

```
$ TZ='US/Pacific' awk -f tst.awk file
20200804T151806.214 PDT,2003060015,2003060018
20200804T162027.571 PDT,2005260045,2005260095
20200804T162027.572 PDT,2005260045,2005260095
20200804T170119.715 PDT,2005290022C,2005290042D
20200804T170119.715 PDT,2005290022C,2005290042D
20200731T170326.111 PDT,2005290028C,2005290050D
20191231T160326.111 PST,2005290028C,2005290050D
19991231T160326.111 PST,2005290028C,2005290050D
```

If that TZ values doesn't work for you there's probably one that does. FWIW here's the list on my Mac:

```
$ sudo systemsetup -listtimezones
Time Zones:
 Africa/Abidjan
 Africa/Accra
 Africa/Addis_Ababa
 Africa/Algiers
 Africa/Asmara
 Africa/Bamako
 Africa/Bangui
 Africa/Banjul
 Africa/Bissau
 Africa/Blantyre
 Africa/Brazzaville
 Africa/Bujumbura
 Africa/Cairo
 Africa/Casablanca
 Africa/Ceuta
 Africa/Conakry
 Africa/Dakar
 Africa/Dar_es_Salaam
 Africa/Djibouti
 Africa/Douala
 Africa/El_Aaiun
 Africa/Freetown
 Africa/Gaborone
 Africa/Harare
 Africa/Johannesburg
 Africa/Juba
 Africa/Kampala
 Africa/Khartoum
 Africa/Kigali
 Africa/Kinshasa
 Africa/Lagos
 Africa/Libreville
 Africa/Lome
 Africa/Luanda
 Africa/Lubumbashi
 Africa/Lusaka
 Africa/Malabo
 Africa/Maputo
 Africa/Maseru
 Africa/Mbabane
 Africa/Mogadishu
 Africa/Monrovia
 Africa/Nairobi
 Africa/Ndjamena
 Africa/Niamey
 Africa/Nouakchott
 Africa/Ouagadougou
 Africa/Porto-Novo
 Africa/Sao_Tome
 Africa/Tripoli
 Africa/Tunis
 Africa/Windhoek
 America/Adak
 America/Anchorage
 America/Anguilla
 America/Antigua
 America/Araguaina
 America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
 America/Argentina/Catamarca
 America/Argentina/Cordoba
 America/Argentina/Jujuy
 America/Argentina/La_Rioja
 America/Argentina/Mendoza
 America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos
 America/Argentina/Salta
 America/Argentina/San_Juan
 America/Argentina/San_Luis
 America/Argentina/Tucuman
 America/Argentina/Ushuaia
 America/Aruba
 America/Asuncion
 America/Atikokan
 America/Bahia
 America/Bahia_Banderas
 America/Barbados
 America/Belem
 America/Belize
 America/Blanc-Sablon
 America/Boa_Vista
 America/Bogota
 America/Boise
 America/Cambridge_Bay
 America/Campo_Grande
 America/Cancun
 America/Caracas
 America/Cayenne
 America/Cayman
 America/Chicago
 America/Chihuahua
 America/Costa_Rica
 America/Creston
 America/Cuiaba
 America/Curacao
 America/Danmarkshavn
 America/Dawson
 America/Dawson_Creek
 America/Denver
 America/Detroit
 America/Dominica
 America/Edmonton
 America/Eirunepe
 America/El_Salvador
 America/Fort_Nelson
 America/Fortaleza
 America/Glace_Bay
 America/Godthab
 America/Goose_Bay
 America/Grand_Turk
 America/Grenada
 America/Guadeloupe
 America/Guatemala
 America/Guayaquil
 America/Guyana
 America/Halifax
 America/Havana
 America/Hermosillo
 America/Indiana/Indianapolis
 America/Indiana/Knox
 America/Indiana/Marengo
 America/Indiana/Petersburg
 America/Indiana/Tell_City
 America/Indiana/Vevay
 America/Indiana/Vincennes
 America/Indiana/Winamac
 America/Inuvik
 America/Iqaluit
 America/Jamaica
 America/Juneau
 America/Kentucky/Louisville
 America/Kentucky/Monticello
 America/Kralendijk
 America/La_Paz
 America/Lima
 America/Los_Angeles
 America/Lower_Princes
 America/Maceio
 America/Managua
 America/Manaus
 America/Marigot
 America/Martinique
 America/Matamoros
 America/Mazatlan
 America/Menominee
 America/Merida
 America/Metlakatla
 America/Mexico_City
 America/Miquelon
 America/Moncton
 America/Monterrey
 America/Montevideo
 America/Montreal
 America/Montserrat
 America/Nassau
 America/New_York
 America/Nipigon
 America/Nome
 America/Noronha
 America/North_Dakota/Beulah
 America/North_Dakota/Center
 America/North_Dakota/New_Salem
 America/Nuuk
 America/Ojinaga
 America/Panama
 America/Pangnirtung
 America/Paramaribo
 America/Phoenix
 America/Port-au-Prince
 America/Port_of_Spain
 America/Porto_Velho
 America/Puerto_Rico
 America/Punta_Arenas
 America/Rainy_River
 America/Rankin_Inlet
 America/Recife
 America/Regina
 America/Resolute
 America/Rio_Branco
 America/Santa_Isabel
 America/Santarem
 America/Santiago
 America/Santo_Domingo
 America/Sao_Paulo
 America/Scoresbysund
 America/Shiprock
 America/Sitka
 America/St_Barthelemy
 America/St_Johns
 America/St_Kitts
 America/St_Lucia
 America/St_Thomas
 America/St_Vincent
 America/Swift_Current
 America/Tegucigalpa
 America/Thule
 America/Thunder_Bay
 America/Tijuana
 America/Toronto
 America/Tortola
 America/Vancouver
 America/Whitehorse
 America/Winnipeg
 America/Yakutat
 America/Yellowknife
 Antarctica/Casey
 Antarctica/Davis
 Antarctica/DumontDUrville
 Antarctica/Macquarie
 Antarctica/Mawson
 Antarctica/McMurdo
 Antarctica/Palmer
 Antarctica/Rothera
 Antarctica/South_Pole
 Antarctica/Syowa
 Antarctica/Troll
 Antarctica/Vostok
 Arctic/Longyearbyen
 Asia/Aden
 Asia/Almaty
 Asia/Amman
 Asia/Anadyr
 Asia/Aqtau
 Asia/Aqtobe
 Asia/Ashgabat
 Asia/Atyrau
 Asia/Baghdad
 Asia/Bahrain
 Asia/Baku
 Asia/Bangkok
 Asia/Barnaul
 Asia/Beirut
 Asia/Bishkek
 Asia/Brunei
 Asia/Calcutta
 Asia/Chita
 Asia/Choibalsan
 Asia/Chongqing
 Asia/Colombo
 Asia/Damascus
 Asia/Dhaka
 Asia/Dili
 Asia/Dubai
 Asia/Dushanbe
 Asia/Famagusta
 Asia/Gaza
 Asia/Harbin
 Asia/Hebron
 Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
 Asia/Hong_Kong
 Asia/Hovd
 Asia/Irkutsk
 Asia/Jakarta
 Asia/Jayapura
 Asia/Jerusalem
 Asia/Kabul
 Asia/Kamchatka
 Asia/Karachi
 Asia/Kashgar
 Asia/Kathmandu
 Asia/Katmandu
 Asia/Khandyga
 Asia/Krasnoyarsk
 Asia/Kuala_Lumpur
 Asia/Kuching
 Asia/Kuwait
 Asia/Macau
 Asia/Magadan
 Asia/Makassar
 Asia/Manila
 Asia/Muscat
 Asia/Nicosia
 Asia/Novokuznetsk
 Asia/Novosibirsk
 Asia/Omsk
 Asia/Oral
 Asia/Phnom_Penh
 Asia/Pontianak
 Asia/Pyongyang
 Asia/Qatar
 Asia/Qostanay
 Asia/Qyzylorda
 Asia/Rangoon
 Asia/Riyadh
 Asia/Sakhalin
 Asia/Samarkand
 Asia/Seoul
 Asia/Shanghai
 Asia/Singapore
 Asia/Srednekolymsk
 Asia/Taipei
 Asia/Tashkent
 Asia/Tbilisi
 Asia/Tehran
 Asia/Thimphu
 Asia/Tokyo
 Asia/Tomsk
 Asia/Ulaanbaatar
 Asia/Urumqi
 Asia/Ust-Nera
 Asia/Vientiane
 Asia/Vladivostok
 Asia/Yakutsk
 Asia/Yangon
 Asia/Yekaterinburg
 Asia/Yerevan
 Atlantic/Azores
 Atlantic/Bermuda
 Atlantic/Canary
 Atlantic/Cape_Verde
 Atlantic/Faroe
 Atlantic/Madeira
 Atlantic/Reykjavik
 Atlantic/South_Georgia
 Atlantic/St_Helena
 Atlantic/Stanley
 Australia/Adelaide
 Australia/Brisbane
 Australia/Broken_Hill
 Australia/Currie
 Australia/Darwin
 Australia/Eucla
 Australia/Hobart
 Australia/Lindeman
 Australia/Lord_Howe
 Australia/Melbourne
 Australia/Perth
 Australia/Sydney
 Europe/Amsterdam
 Europe/Andorra
 Europe/Astrakhan
 Europe/Athens
 Europe/Belgrade
 Europe/Berlin
 Europe/Bratislava
 Europe/Brussels
 Europe/Bucharest
 Europe/Budapest
 Europe/Busingen
 Europe/Chisinau
 Europe/Copenhagen
 Europe/Dublin
 Europe/Gibraltar
 Europe/Guernsey
 Europe/Helsinki
 Europe/Isle_of_Man
 Europe/Istanbul
 Europe/Jersey
 Europe/Kaliningrad
 Europe/Kiev
 Europe/Kirov
 Europe/Lisbon
 Europe/Ljubljana
 Europe/London
 Europe/Luxembourg
 Europe/Madrid
 Europe/Malta
 Europe/Mariehamn
 Europe/Minsk
 Europe/Monaco
 Europe/Moscow
 Europe/Oslo
 Europe/Paris
 Europe/Podgorica
 Europe/Prague
 Europe/Riga
 Europe/Rome
 Europe/Samara
 Europe/San_Marino
 Europe/Sarajevo
 Europe/Saratov
 Europe/Simferopol
 Europe/Skopje
 Europe/Sofia
 Europe/Stockholm
 Europe/Tallinn
 Europe/Tirane
 Europe/Ulyanovsk
 Europe/Uzhgorod
 Europe/Vaduz
 Europe/Vatican
 Europe/Vienna
 Europe/Vilnius
 Europe/Volgograd
 Europe/Warsaw
 Europe/Zagreb
 Europe/Zaporozhye
 Europe/Zurich
 GMT
 Indian/Antananarivo
 Indian/Chagos
 Indian/Christmas
 Indian/Cocos
 Indian/Comoro
 Indian/Kerguelen
 Indian/Mahe
 Indian/Maldives
 Indian/Mauritius
 Indian/Mayotte
 Indian/Reunion
 Pacific/Apia
 Pacific/Auckland
 Pacific/Bougainville
 Pacific/Chatham
 Pacific/Chuuk
 Pacific/Easter
 Pacific/Efate
 Pacific/Enderbury
 Pacific/Fakaofo
 Pacific/Fiji
 Pacific/Funafuti
 Pacific/Galapagos
 Pacific/Gambier
 Pacific/Guadalcanal
 Pacific/Guam
 Pacific/Honolulu
 Pacific/Johnston
 Pacific/Kiritimati
 Pacific/Kosrae
 Pacific/Kwajalein
 Pacific/Majuro
 Pacific/Marquesas
 Pacific/Midway
 Pacific/Nauru
 Pacific/Niue
 Pacific/Norfolk
 Pacific/Noumea
 Pacific/Pago_Pago
 Pacific/Palau
 Pacific/Pitcairn
 Pacific/Pohnpei
 Pacific/Ponape
 Pacific/Port_Moresby
 Pacific/Rarotonga
 Pacific/Saipan
 Pacific/Tahiti
 Pacific/Tarawa
 Pacific/Tongatapu
 Pacific/Truk
 Pacific/Wake
 Pacific/Wallis
```

see also under:

```
$ ls -LF /usr/share/zoneinfo
+VERSION     Asia/   CST6CDT  EST      Europe/  GMT+0      Hongkong  Jamaica    MST      Navajo    Portugal   UCT        WET      zone.tab
Africa/      Atlantic/   Canada/  EST5EDT  Factory  GMT-0      Iceland   Japan      MST7MDT  PRC       ROC    US/        Zulu
America/     Australia/  Chile/   Egypt    GB       GMT0       Indian/   Kwajalein  Mexico/  PST8PDT   ROK    UTC        iso3166.tab
Antarctica/  Brazil/     Cuba     Eire     GB-Eire  Greenwich  Iran  Libya      NZ       Pacific/  Singapore  Universal  leapseconds
Arctic/      CET     EET      Etc/     GMT      HST        Israel    MET        NZ-CHAT  Poland    Turkey     W-SU       posixrules
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I finally do this

```
awk -F ',' '{
    sCCYY = substr($1,1,4); 
    sMM = substr($1,5,2); 
    sDD = substr($1,7,2); 
    stime = substr($1,10,6) - 80000; 
    if (stime < 0) { 
        sDD = sDD - 1; 
        stime = 160000 + substr($1,10,6); 
        if (sDD <= 0) { 
            sMM = sMM - 1; 
            if (sMM == 1 || sMM == 3 || sMM == 5 || sMM == 7 || sMM == 8 || sMM == 10 || sMM == 12 ) sDD = 31; 
            else if (sMM == 4 || sMM == 6 || sMM == 9 || sMM == 11) sDD = 30; 
            else if (sMM == 0) sDD = 31; 
            else if (sCCYY%4 == 0) sDD = 29; 
            else sDD = 28; 
            if (sMM <= 0) { sCCYY = sCCYY - 1; sMM = 12; } 
            } 
        } 
        printf"%04s%02s%02sT%06s%s%s\n",sCCYY,sMM,sDD,stime,substr($1,16,4) " PDT","," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8 "," $9 "," $10 "," $11; 
}' test.txt


Result:
20200804T161806.214 PDT,2003060015,2003060018
20200804T172027.571 PDT,2005260045,2005260095
20200804T172027.572 PDT,2005260045,2005260095
20200804T170119.715 PDT,2005290022C,2005290042D
20200229T160119.715 PDT,2005290022C,2005290042D
20210228T160119.715 PDT,2005290022C,2005290042D
20200731T160326.111 PDT,2005290028C,2005290050D
20191231T160326.111 PDT,2005290028C,2005290050D
19991231T160326.111 PDT,2005290028C,2005290050D
```