# Convert GMT with offset string to MST in bash Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, date, timezone, date-conversion

I have a String variable (datetime with GMT offset) in the following format.
How can I convert this to a MST in bash shell script?

```
Input GMT :- 08/Sep/2020:11:38:01 +0000

Output MST :- 08/Sep/2020:04:38:01 -0700
```

We can get the offset like this

```
offset=$(date +%-z)
```

I dont want to again convert into date from string and then use offset and minus offset to reach MST.Is there a way to convert it in a better way?

Comment: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642166/unix-convert-gmt-time-field-to-pst-time/63642486#63642486) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @vgersh99 but this thread doesnt have the offset for the TZ

Comment: that's what the `%z` is for. This was meant as a "starting point" - not as a complete solution. You'll have to "massage" it a bit, but the idea core is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `08/Sep/2020:11:38:01 +0000` with `bash` to `08 Sep 2020 11:38:01 +0000`:

```
gmt="08/Sep/2020:11:38:01 +0000"
gmt="${gmt//\// }"                # replace all / with spaces
gmt="${gmt/:/ }"                  # replace first : with space
```

Then use it with GNU date:

```
TZ="MST" date --date="$gmt" +'%d/%h/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z'
```

Output:

```
08/Sep/2020:04:38:01 -0700
```